# Trying to generify method with ResponseEntity and RestTemplate

Tags: java, generics

I have the method below where I am trying to make it more generic so that the method can take any type I want:

```java
public PersonResult getAllPersons (PersonMeta meta) {
    final String uri = addParams(getURI(), meta);
    final ResponseEntity<PersonResult> response = this.restTemplate.getForEntity(uri, PersonResult .class);
    if (HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.equals(response.getStatusCode())) {
        throw new HttpClientErrorException("There are no persons available.");
    }
    return response.getBody();
}
```

My try: but returns `NullPointerException at response position`

```java
public <T, R> R getAllPersons (T meta) {
    final String uri = addParams(getURI(), meta);
    final ResponseEntity<R> response = (ResponseEntity<R>) this.restTemplate.getForEntity(uri, Object.class);
    if (HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.equals(response.getStatusCode())) {
        throw new HttpClientErrorException("There are no persons available.");
    }
    return response.getBody();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the result class as a parameter also.

```java
public <T, R> R getAllPersons(T meta, Class<R> resultClass) {
    final String uri = addParams(getURI(), meta);
    final ResponseEntity<R> response = this.restTemplate.getForEntity(uri, resultClass);
    if (HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.equals(response.getStatusCode())) {
        throw new HttpClientErrorException("There are no persons available.");
    }
    return response.getBody();
}
```